# The number of the subset(What point do I have a mistake)[easy question]

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

$Q)$ Let the $U = \{1,2,3,4,5,...,10\}$ and its subset $A, B$

Find the number of the ordered pair $(A,B)$ satisfying the all the (1) and (2)

$(1)$ $\Vert A  \Vert \leq \Vert B  \Vert$

$(2)$ $\Vert A  \cap B \Vert = 4$ and $\Vert A  \cup B \Vert = U$

---

The answer is at the bottom of this post.

As you might see, This is a really easy and elementary question in my lecture's note. He doesn't add his solution in his note. Plus I don't know why my answer is false.

My attempt) 
Deciding the element for the $\Vert A  \cap B \Vert = 4$ first, So  ${10 \choose 4}$

And there are 4 possibilities that $(\Vert A-(A\cap B)  \Vert , \Vert B-(A\cap B)  \Vert)$ $\in \{(6,0),(5,1),(4,2),(3,3)\} $

So only we have to do just choosing the element in $B$, so there are ${6 \choose 0} + {6 \choose 1} + {6 \choose 2}+{6 \choose 3}$

Hence the my answer is ${10 \choose 4} \times ({6 \choose 0} + {6 \choose 1} + {6 \choose 2}+{6 \choose 3})$ = $8820$

But the answer was 19320. Still I don't know what point I've missed.

I believe that the lecture's answer is incorret.

Comment: I agree with your method, although I think your final answer should be $8820=210 \times (1+6+15+20)$, not $8320$.

Comment: Yes. I calculated again. My answer was incorrect. You are right. I edited my answer. I have a confidence that lecture's answer is incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach and result are correct; if you rendered the problem correctly, the lecturer’s answer appears to be wrong.

Note that you counted for $|A|\ge|B|$ instead of $|A|\le|B|$, but of course the result is the same.